# GCP Load Balancer not created when deployment is exposed

Tags: kubernetes

I've a created Kubernetes v1.12.0 cluster on GCP consisting of 3 controller VMs and 3 node VMs, all running Ubuntu 18-04 LTS (Kernel 4.15.0-1025-gcp)

I'm using weave v2.5.0 for networking and everything works fine except no load balancer is created which I expose a simple webserver. I think the problem is due to some omission on my part regarding my GCP configuration rather than a bug in Kubernetes

I've placed all the VMs in an unmanaged GCP cluster labelled kubernetes like this

```
gcloud compute instance-groups unmanaged create kubernetes
gcloud compute instance-groups unmanaged add-instances kubernetes --instances gke-controller-0,gke-controller-1,gke-controller-2,gke-worker-0,gke-worker-1,gke-worker-2
```

The network is labelled kubernetes-the-hard-way and the subnet is labelled kubernetes

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80 
kubectl expose deploy nginx--port=80 --name=nginx --type=LoadBalancer
```

The External IP stays in Pending state:

```
kubectl get svc nginx
NAME    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
nginx   LoadBalancer   10.32.0.198   <pending>     80:31756/TCP   33m

kubectl describe svc nginx
Name:                     nginx
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=nginx
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.32.0.198
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31756/TCP
Endpoints:                10.200.1.15:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

kubectl get svc nginx -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "39375"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/nginx
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.32.0.198
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31756
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

kubectl get ep
NAME         ENDPOINTS                                            AGE
kubernetes   10.240.0.10:6443,10.240.0.11:6443,10.240.0.12:6443   23h
nginx        10.200.1.15:80                                       42m
```

I've checked the event log and all the pod logs and no issues are reported.

The kube-apiserver.service contains et al:

```
--cloud-provider=gce \
--cloud-config=/var/lib/kubernetes/gce.conf \
--cloud-provider-gce-lb-src-cidrs=35.204.0.0/16,107.178.0.0/16 \
```

/var/lib/kubernetes/gce.conf:

```
[global] 
token-url = nil 
project-id = first-outlet-221910 
network = kubernetes-the-hard-way 
subnetwork = kubernetes 
node-instance-prefix = gke- 
node-tags = controller, kubernetes-the-hard-way, worker
```

Please could someone explain the correct value for token-url if my entry is incorrect? Also, have I made any other errors/omissions which are causing this problem?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you've considered to expose any web resource outside the cluster using External IP, Kubernetes provides [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) mechanism to establish HTTP and HTTPS routes to your internal services.

However, when we talk about running cluster on GCP,  [HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) is created by default in GKE, once `Ingress` resource has been implemented successfully, therefore it will take care for routing all the external HTTP/S traffic to the nested Kubernetes services.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: web
    servicePort: 8080
```

You can check External IP for Ingress resource:

`kubectl get ingress basic-ingress`

Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) for more information about exposing the web application through Ingress service in GCP.

And [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/deploy/glbc/gce.conf) is example for `gce.conf` file.

Comment: How can you debug if the ingress is not getting associated with it's external IP? I've been waiting a few hours and the load balancer is not getting creatd